# Column validation user message pops up for millisecond

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column, column-validation

So I got this column validation:
=[Sleep]>TODAY()

And user message "NO".

And it works, I cant put a date back in time, but the user message "NO" is just popping up for a millisecond, someone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

The column validation will not take effect unless you try to save a new item or save the changes made to an existing item.

[image]

I’ve run tests with “Require that this column contains information” set to “Yes” or “No”, in both classic and modern experience and I cannot reproduce this issue in my environment.

Maybe you can switch to another list and see if you will run into same issue.

See my test results below:

[image: Modern experience]

[image: Classic experience]